# How is the extracted information brought back to reality?

Tags: plot-explanation, inception

In the film Inception assuming Cobb was successfully able to extract Saito's secrets from the safe how would he **bring** those papers stamped "confidential" to the reality?

The only way I can think is to memorize each line on that paper, wake up and recite those lines to Cobol Engineering before he forgets.

Answer (score 12):

I can't do much more than confirm what you already assumed, too:

> The only way I can think is to memorize each line on that paper, wake up and recite those lines to Cobol Engineering before he forgets.

This indeed seems to be the intended approach. But I don't think you necessarily need to memorize each line, though. Those letters are likely not actual official letters anyway, but most probably rather sketches of his overall ideas and plans, seeing that we're in a dream and this whole documents in a safe concept has a rather metaphorical nature in the first place. It abstracts the detailed intricacies of his plans into a very concrete and broad form. Just learning the key points of his plans should be already be enough information for Cobol Engineering.

---

Let me elaborate a little more on the overall problem of this question (don't get me wrong, it isn't a bad question). The fact that the movie doesn't really explain how this whole extraction actually works, is to some degree intentional, I think, and goes hand in hand with its whole dream-aspect. All we can assume from this process of reading a letter in Saito's dream-safe is, that **Cobb actually *steals a thought* from Saito**. How this actually pans out in reality or how this thought is structued is **beyond the purpose of this movie**. We are just not supposed to care about the neurological reality of those things. All we know is that **Cobb then *somehow* knows what Saito knows**.

By employing this escape into the dream-world, where everything is possible and where very abstract processes are represented by very concrete and tangible items and actions, the movie not only gets to "plausibly" show unusual things, like zero-gravity or stuff appearing out of nowhere, but it also achieves to completely remove the **need** to give explanations for such abstract processes like stealing a thought or learning things. The sometimes rather lame excuse answers like *"it works somehow"*/*"that's the way it's written"*/*"the movie doesn't explain"* are therefore the *exact* answers in the context of this movie. ***Inception* achieved to remove any need for plausible explanations without actually being implausible**, by employing this whole dream-metaphor, where the most difficult and abstract psychological processes are as easy as reading a letter or giving a windmill to a child. This transformation of abstract matters into tangible and clear imagery is just part of the movie's very theme.

Comment: Won't these "key points" run into various paragraphs depending on the subject's plan? Now let's say Saito had his plans in Japanese, would Cobb memorize the shape of each letter if he didn't understand it?

Comment: @A.Jesin  They're not *real documents*, just the thrust of what Saito is trying to keep hidden. Saito has obviously memorized them, why wouldn't Cobb be able to?

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Assume you are a doctor. I'm an extractor with little knowledge on medical science. Would I be able to memorize your patient histories and recollect them accurately in reality?

Comment: I think that is taking this situation out of context, somewhat. Perhaps if Cobb needed to extract incredibly specific medical knowledge, he would take a doctor on his team to digest the information more effectively. He's just trying to find what Cobol's intentions are: the information could be as simple as 'Aggressive acquisition of this company, followed by merger with this company..." We don't know, but we have to assume he knows what he's doing, as he's clearly effective. The target data can't be beyond human recollection, otherwise Saito wouldn't have it in his head...

Comment: @A.Jesin In addition to what *John* said, that it isn't about any particular paragraphs, I would add (though he's touched that already, too), that this whole dream concept has a very metaphorical nature, upto the point where all those material objects in the dream actually have a much more "vague" reality. You could thus go as far as interpreting the act of reading a hidden letter from *Saito*'s dream safe as merely *stealing a thought from him*, which then is in *Cobb*'s mind, however that thought is actually structured. But how this *really* works is just beyond the movie's imagery/purpose.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I understand entire "metaphor" thing. My question is about the extractor bringing these thoughts/ideas of a subject to reality and delivering it to their clients. If a person lectures for an hour he/she is giving you some of their thoughts. If it is of a topic that you cannot understand (rocket science) will you be able to "carry" this thought and lecture someone else?

Comment: @A.Jesin I don't know and agree that this remains unclear. But in the same way I don't think this is explained by the movie in any way either *but* this isn't the purpose of the movie, which left many of the more substantial questions unanswered, but to some degree intentionally, I think. For now I'd say we can and should just assume that *Saito*'s thoughts in this regard are simple/general enough for *Cobb* to understand and memorize them in some way or another. Every situation beyond that as well as *Cobb*'s possible approach to it seems rather speculative to me.

Comment: While this might come across as a simple easy-out *"we shouldn't care nor udnerstand, it probably works somehow"*-escape, this is in fact the correct approach for the concepts of this movie, I think. Not because it's all made up rubbish (well, it is, but nevermind), but because the movie IMHO enforces this approach by employing a kind of imagery in the dreams that gives many deliberately "vague" concepts a very concrete and tangible representation *in order* to free the viewer from actually reasoning about their workings in reality. In the same way a dream does.

Comment: By playing with this dream-like substantialization of very abstract concepts, the movie achieves to free itself from the responsibility of explaining their actual workings. It thus manages to drop the "science"-aspect from the *science fiction* genre without delving into the pure *fantasy* genre. A science fiction movie without the need for plausible science. But I guess I'm divigating a bit.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson I agree with your last comment. Even though Cobb and his teammates were extractors by profession the movie didn't show us a single incident of successful extraction :-)

Comment: @A.Jesin: It wasn't the point of the film. They were extractors, who had to try *inception*, i.e. implanting ideas instead of stealing them.